# Android Instant apps not visible on google search

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

We are trying to experience the Instant App feature which supported by existing apps such as [BuzzFeed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buzzfeed.android&hl=en), B&H, [Wish](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contextlogic.wish&hl=en), Viki and others. And we couldn't see those instant app links on google search on all our devices(Galaxy Note5, Galaxy S7 Edge and Galaxy A5) which running Android 7.0

All our devices have following settings

1. Instant app feature enabled on all devices via Google settings which
   is available on our devices
2. Chrome browser used for instant app search signed in using play store gmail accounts

Can you please advice why we cannot access those instant apps on our devices? Any limitation by country and device types ? Or anybody can share the direct links for any of those app to try on our devices ? (As per google documentation country and device seems eligible in our case)

**Note:** Anyway we able to run own Instant app from Android Studio and using adb command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "Url of instant app"
```

Comment: Are you sure Galaxy Note5 and Galaxy A5 are supported devices?

Comment: Only Galaxy S7 explicitly mentioned over our tested devices on official page https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#general. Unfortunately couldn't test on any nexus or pixel devices. is that Instant feature (via Google Settings on phone) available on devices doesn't mean eligible for instant app ? Because we able to activate this on devices we mentioned above.

Comment: Try with emulators of supported devices. It works fine with emulators in my case.

Comment: This is most likely because you are in a country that doesn’t support Instant Apps atm. Devices/emulators from those countries will not be able to see Instant Apps in the results such as BuzzFeed, B&H, etc.. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861#production

Comment: Btw, all countries are supported now, so this should no longer be a possible issue.

Comment: I hope your problems has been solved.